# using addEventListener to live copy to a summary page, running into a bit of an issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, attachevent

I'm a javascript/jQuery No0b and looking to use the addEventListener to print progress in a summary page.  this is a 4 tabbed form.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="summaryCustomerName"></td>
    <td id="summaryAccountManager"></td>
    <td id="summaryDescription"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="summaryAccountCoordinator1"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Portion of JS:

```
(function(){
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
  document.getElementById("accountCoordinator1").addEventListener("change", accountCoordinator1GV, false);

  } 
  else if (window.attachEvent) {
  document.getElementById("accountCoordinator1").attachEvent("change", accountCoordinator1GV);
  }
});
```

This works just fine, I am trying to get ONLY the **customerDescription** portion into a **`<div class='summaryDIV'>`** + customerDescription + **`</div>`**

The portion I am having problems with:

```
var accountCoordinator1GV = function () {
    var accountCoordinator1GV = "<h3>Account Coordinator</h3>" + "<div class='summaryDIV'>" + accountCoordinator1GV + "</div>";
    accountCoordinator1GV += document.getElementById("accountCoordinator1").value;
    document.getElementById("summaryAccountCoordinator1").innerHTML = accountCoordinator1GV;
};
```

I've tried other methods such as:

```
 var accountCoordinator1GV = function () {
    var accountCoordinator1GV = $("#accountCoordinator1").val();
    var ac1DIV = "<div class='summaryDIV'>" + accountCoordinator1GV + "</div>";
    $("#summaryAccountCoordinator1").append(ac1DIV);
};
```

HELP!  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code as it's whole function:

```
(function(){

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        document.getElementById("customerName").addEventListener("change", customerNameGV, false);
        document.getElementById("accountManager").addEventListener("change", accountManagerGV, false);
        document.getElementById("customerDescription").addEventListener("change", customerDescriptionGV, false);
        document.getElementById("accountCoordinator1").addEventListener("change", accountCoordinator1GV, false);
        document.getElementById("ContactSubmitButton").addEventListener("click", CompanyContacts, false);

    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        document.getElementById("customerName").attachEvent("change", generalInformation);
        document.getElementById("accountManager").attachEvent("change", accountManagerGV);
        document.getElementById("customerDescription").attachEvent("change", customerDescriptionGV);
        document.getElementById("accountCoordinator1").attachEvent("change", accountCoordinator1GV);
        document.getElementById("ContactSubmitButton").attachEvent("click", CompanyContacts);
    }
});

var customerNameGV = function () {
    var customerNameGV = "<h3>Customer Name</h3>";
    customerNameGV += document.getElementById("customerName").value;
        document.getElementById("summaryCustomerName").innerHTML = customerNameGV;
};

var accountManagerGV = function () {
    var accountManagerGV = "<h3>Account Manager</h3>";
        accountManagerGV += document.getElementById("accountManager").value;
        document.getElementById("summaryAccountManager").innerHTML = accountManagerGV;
};

var customerDescriptionGV = function () {
    var customerDescriptionGV = "<h3>Customer Description</h3>";
    customerDescriptionGV += document.getElementById("customerDescription").value;
    document.getElementById("summaryDescription").innerHTML = customerDescriptionGV;
};

var accountCoordinator1GV = function () {
    var accountCoordinator1GV = "<h3>Account Coordinator</h3>" + "<div class='summaryDIV'>" + accountCoordinator1GV + "</div>";
    accountCoordinator1GV += document.getElementById("accountCoordinator1").value;
    document.getElementById("summaryAccountCoordinator1").innerHTML = accountCoordinator1GV;
};

var accountCoordinator1GV = function () {
    var accountCoordinator1GV = $("#accountCoordinator1").val();
    var ac1DIV = "<div class='summaryDIV'>" + accountCoordinator1GV + "</div>";
    $("#summaryAccountCoordinator1").append(ac1DIV);
};

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap

```
var ac1DIV = "<div class='summaryDIV'>" + accountCoordinator1GV + "</div>";
```

as

```
var ac1DIV = $("<div class='summaryDIV'>" + accountCoordinator1GV + "</div>");
```

---

try

```
var accountCoordinator1GV = function () {
    var accountCoordinator1GV = $("#accountCoordinator1").val();
    var ac1DIV = $("<div class='summaryDIV'>" + accountCoordinator1GV + "</div>");
    $("#summaryAccountCoordinator1").append(ac1DIV);
};
```

Comment: ok, now I'm having an issue with duplication.  this is for a <textarea> and each selection I make in that ONE drop down, it duplicates the entire code, I need it to replace the existing data to match the change of selection if a change needs to be made.

Comment: could you show me a live sample at http://jsfiddle.net, I can't see any `<textarea>` in you code. you'd better not use `innerHTML`

Comment: Sorry, decided to add a new posting due to the new issue.  it was a select option dropdown, sorry.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182249/addeventlistener-duplicating-select-options-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!  This is what I did to resolve the issue, stupid mistake, thanks a TON for the catch!

```
var accountCoordinator1GV = function () {
    var accountCoordinator1GV = $("#accountCoordinator1").val();
    var ac1DIV = $("<h3>Account Coordinator</h3>" + "<div class='summaryDIV'>" + accountCoordinator1GV + "</div>");
    $("#summaryAccountCoordinator1").append(ac1DIV);
};
```