# addEventListener duplicating Select Options Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates, addeventlistener, attachevent

I created a javascript function to copy data from an input on another `jQuery` tab to a Summary tab. I am having an issue with duplication with a dropdown.

I need for it to replace the exisiting information when choosing another selection if a change is needed.

**HTML - Dropdown**

```
<select id="accountCoordinator1" class="txtbxList">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option>Jon</option>
  <option>Lori</option>
</select>
```

**HTML - Placement**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="summaryAccountCoordinator1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function(){

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        document.getElementById("accountCoordinator1").addEventListener("change", accountCoordinator1GV, false);

    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        document.getElementById("accountCoordinator1").attachEvent("change", accountCoordinator1GV);
    }
});

var accountCoordinator1GV = function () {
    var accountCoordinator1GV = $("#accountCoordinator1").val();
    var ac1DIV = $("<h3>Account Coordinator</h3>" + "<div class='summaryDIV'>" + accountCoordinator1GV + "</div>");
    $("#summaryAccountCoordinator1").append(ac1DIV);
};

});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace the existing information, use `.html()` instead of `.append()`. It might be easier to just change the text of `.summaryDIV`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accountCoordinator1").change(function() {
        $("#summaryAccountCoordinator1 .summaryDIV").text($(this).val());
    });
});
```